# Loop through html classes but only hide the one that has been clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm pretty sure this can be done i just don't know how to i don't mind whether the solution is pure js or jquery.

```
z[i].childNodes[1].childNodes[3].childNodes[1].childNodes[1].childNodes[0].onclick=function(){
   document.getElementsByClassName('cq-proceed')[0].style="display:block !important;";
   var q = document.getElementsByClassName('hide_me');
   for(var r = 0; r < q.length; r++){
        q[r].style="display:none;";
       }
  }
```

this snippit of code above is inside another loop, basically z[i] gives me the parent node for every option div and then i just chain child nodes together so that i can have a reference to the input button every time, that being the first input radio button. How do i only hide the class what i have clicked if they all have the same class name without using a 0 index or id because i have 50 sets of these forms.

```
<div class="option c_questions yes-stop">
 <dl>
 <dt>
  <label>Are you experiencing acid reflux at least twice a week? </label
 </dt>
 <dd>
  <ul id="options-11589-list" class="options-list">
  <li>
      **<input type="radio" class="radio  validate-one-required-by-name product-custom-option" onclick="dependentOptions.select(this);opConfig.reloadPrice();" name="options[11589]" id="options_11589_1" value="26996">**
      <span class="label"><label for="options_11589_1">Yes </label></span>
  </li>

  <li> 
    <input type="radio" class="radio  validate-one-required-by-name product-custom-option" onclick="dependentOptions.select(this);opConfig.reloadPrice();" name="options[11589]" id="options_11589_2" value="26997">
     <span class="label"><label for="options_11589_2">No </label></span>
  </li>
  <p class="hide_me" style="display: none;">Unfortunatley based on this condition you do not qualify</p>
</ul>                                    
</dd>
</dl>
</div>
```

Comment: whuch element you want to target can you highlight it from html?

Comment: its the one with ** ** wrapped round it